# Web application in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I installed ASP.NET and web development && .NET Core cross-platform development in Visual Studio 2019, I can't find web application (Model-View-Controller) in the list of ASP.NET Core web application.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't go far enough.  Go ahead and select **ASP.NET Core Web Application**:

[image]

Then click the **Next** button and fill out the "Configure your New Project" form.

[image]

Click the **Create** button.  You'll then get this dialog:

[image]

If you're still not seeing the ASP.NET Core Web Application project template, open the Visual Studio Installer and check the payloads:

[image]

Comment: Yes dear Thank you but in the last step i can't find Web Application (Model - View - Controller),

Comment: I want to know what should I modify to add this please!

Comment: See my answer update.

Comment: Thank you again, I noticed that I have not all individual components that appear in the picture, but I want you to define the specific component which responsible for web application (Model-View-Controller)

Comment: It's the one that I have circled in the picture above.

Comment: Thanks Robert
I want to know what exactly "Individual Components" that should I install it to appear "Web Application (Model-View-Controller)" in the list of "ASP.Net Core Web Application.